# “I'd swing for him”

Tags: british-english, slang

I occasionally hear this phrase from English characters on the telly, and struggle to guess whether it means “I'd welcome an opportunity to swing a fist at him” or “I'd willingly swing from the gallows for killing him,” or something else entirely.

Comment: It could probably mean either one depending on the context...

Comment: PS. We don’t have death penalty in UK these days so not many gallows around.

Comment: @k1eran It would not be the only stock phrase to outlive its natural context.

Answer (score 2):

I've always taken it for granted that it means "I'd happily murder him even though I would be hanged for it" (before the abolition of capital punishment in the UK).

However, [this](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/swing-for.html) British person seems to have other ideas.